# what is the scenerio for Avro that Json does not fit

Tags: json, apache-kafka, avro

I'm using Avro for feeding Kafka system and I'm wondering why Avro is been created and for which situation should we prefer Avro to Json.

Is it right that Json is more for internet communication, like RESTful request, and Avro is more for Hadoop ecosystem?

I googled some answers and they compare compressed data size and efficiency but I'm not sure that's enough to create a new stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed restful requests usually exchange data using json.

Size and efficiency is a valid reason. It saves bandwidth, memory and storage space. By comparison with json, it is also very cpu friendly for operations such as accessing certain fields without loading the entire message in memory.

Handling more efficiently individual messages makes it a lot easier to scale an application that must handle millions of them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you give me a small example about **accessing certain fields without loading the entire message**, please? I think this is a really interesting feature about Avro.

Comment: When reading the data, you can use a schema definition that only contains the fields you are interested in. Avro will then skip those you left out. In practice, when reading you specify two schemas, the original writer schema, and the reader schema which has only the fields you want. This relies on schema resolution feature of avro. It was primarily designed to allow additions of fields on the publishing side, while consumers can still read new messages with the old schema.